# Importing shape in PostGIS using QGIS failed

Tags: qgis, postgis, import

I tried to import a building-shapefile (ax_gebaeude) into the postgis database (PostgreSQL 11). I normally use QGIS 3.12 with drag & drop for that. In this case I get an error message:

```
Failed to import some layers!

Creation of fields failed
```

The layer can be openend by QGIS or ArcGIS Pro without any problems. I also tried to use the tool fixe geometries before. I renamend all columns in small letters. I tried to export the file via ArcGIS, to get rid of the problems but the problem remains.

Any ideas?

The field names are:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For PostgreSQL there are some system columns that are reserved and cannot be used. But there should be a better error message, as per the bug report:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/26246

But you cannot have columns with these names:

```
tableoid
xmin
cmin
xmax
cmax
ctid
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-system-columns.html

So for your table. xmin and xmax should be changed to x_min x_max for example.